# Xubuntu boot time slowed after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: boot, xubuntu, startup

I run xubuntu 12.10 on a HP netbook N455.
Before the upgrade a few days ago my xubuntu was responsive at boot after 58 seconds - the desktop showed up a few seconds earlier. 
Now, after the upgrade to 12.10 my desktop is responsive after about 110 seconds, i.e., 1 minute 45 seconds.

The whole point of having xubuntu on my netbook seemed to have vanished. 
I checked the startup apps but the list is the same as before the upgrade. 
How can I tell why booting takes so long? Is 12.10 supposed to be so much slower?

Answer (score 1):

My PC used to boot Xubuntu 12.10 (installed on a SSD) within just 5 seconds after grub loaded, but somehow, it become very slow recently , which takes about 40-50 seconds to see the desktop , so I removed all my xfce & gnome config files in my home directory, and it start booting fast again.  finally I figured out that my `~/.fonts` is the causing the problem.

Now my Xubuntu boots as fast as before after all my fonts is moved to:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/my-fonts-folder.
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a .fonts folder in my home dir. How did you find out that this was the cause? Maybe I have a similar issue caused by something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a fresh install instead of an upgrade. I believe that then you will get your boot time were it belongs.
Upgrades are really not advisable because packages get broken and all sort of things.
If you are worried about your files you can always keep a separate home partition and you only need to format the root `/`